# the namespace .. already contains a definition for

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

**Why am I getting this exception, even though I only have 1 `OnUnzipHttpTriggered` defined?**

[image]

I did a global search:

[image]

And it showed that indeed I had only 1 one of these classes defined:

[image]

What I have tried:

1. rebuilt
2. restarted visual studio
3. checked code in and got latest

**Why am I getting this exception?**

Here's my VS info:

[image]

Comment: Maybe the namespace having the same name as a part of it is the problem, try changing the namespace to something else

Comment: @Menahem there are other functions in the same solution that have namespaces that contain the class name, like this one, yet there is no problem with them. gut shabbos!

Comment: Looks like my comment is the same your approved answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the *first* result in your search. It states pretty clearly that `DestinationFileNamer.cs` has the namespace `AlidadeUtilities.OnUnzipHttpTriggered.Extensions`. That's where the problem is, because both the class **and** (part of) the namespace of that file are `AlidadeUtilities.OnUnzipHttpTriggered`.

A class cannot have the same name as a namespace in the same namespace as where the class is.

By the way, just a tip: anything starting with *On* sounds a LOT like an event handler. Please reconsider the name.

**EDIT:**

The full name of the class you're creating is this:
**AlidadeUtilities.OnUnzipHttpTriggered**

The namespace of the class `DestinationFileNamer` is this:
**AlidadeUtilities.OnUnzipHttpTriggered**.Extensions

Your problem is *the fact that those two bold parts are the same*.

**Solution:**
The solution would be to either rename the class `OnUnzipHttpTriggered` or rename the namespace `AlidadeUtilities.OnUnzipHttpTriggered**.Extensions`.

Comment: i really appreciate your answer but im not if i understand?

Comment: i've renamed my namespace `AlidadeUtilities.OnUnzipHttpTriggered.Extensions` to `AlidadeUtilities.Extensions` and that seemed to have resolved the issue, but my mind is boggled right now, im not sure i understand why that is

Comment: thank you for that comment regarding `On` ... this is how my company names their functions, is it not appropriate to name it this way when it is http triggered?

Comment: Anything named `On`SomethingHappened adheres to the default Event Delegate Signature. The standard is `OnEventRaised`. So naming a class like that doesn't feel too good. Source: [Event Delegate Signatures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/event-pattern#event-delegate-signatures)

Answer (score 6):

Reload the visual studio code window by Ctrl+shift+P and then search for Reload window. This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks.
Worked for me but I wonder why it happened. 
It is a fresh project created a few minutes ago with dotnet CLI webapp template.

Answer (score 1):

Some other ways to find the problem:

1. Generate a class diagram and examine it
2. comment out this class and examine code for any other references
3. Use a find tool to find this symbol in your codebase. I use AstroGrep.

You also may have a compiled dll (added reference) with an extension method of the same name. In that case you will have to call your class something else.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting and re-creating the file seemed to fix this for me. Renaming it and reversing the rename also seems to work. Looks like a bug.